# Using LocalStorage for html table

Tags: javascript, css

I have been working on an HTML app in order to keep track of dungeons that I have done in world of warcraft weekly by ticking the boxes next to the dungeon names.

I have created the table and the functions for marking the boxes on click as done and they can also be toggled off if needed.

The problem I'm facing is that I don't know how to use `LocalStorage` in order to keep that information when the page refreshes or closes.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".sjitem").click(function() {
      if ($(this).hasClass("done")) {
        $(this).removeClass("done");
      } else {
        $(this).addClass("done");
      }
      localStorage.setItem("sjitem", "done");
    });
  }

);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="header">
  <a href="D:\BFA_Project\Main_BFA.html">Home</a>
  <title>BFA Tracker</title>
</div>

<div id="Dungeondiv">
  <table class="DungeonTableLayout">

    <tr class="sjtable">
      <th id="th-1" class="sjtable">Dungeons</th>
      <th id="th-2" class="sjtable">Weekly<br />Tracker</th>
    </tr>
    <tr class="sjtable">
      <td class="sjtable trlabel">Freehold</td>
      <td class="sjtable sjitem"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="sjtable">
      <td class="sjtable trlabel">Shrine of<br />the Storm</td>
      <td class="sjtable sjitem"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="sjtable">
      <td class="sjtable trlabel">Tol Dagor</td>
      <td class="sjtable sjitem"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="sjtable">
      <td class="sjtable trlabel">Waycrest<br />Manor</td>
      <td class="sjtable sjitem"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="sjtable">
      <td class="sjtable trlabel">Atal'Dazar</td>
      <td class="sjtable sjitem"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="sjtable">
      <td class="sjtable trlabel">The<br />MOTHERLODE!!!</td>
      <td class="sjtable sjitem"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="sjtable">
      <td class="sjtable trlabel">Temple of<br />Sethraliss</td>
      <td class="sjtable sjitem"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="sjtable">
      <td class="sjtable trlabel">The<br />Underrot<br /></td>
      <td class="sjtable sjitem"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="sjtable">
      <td class="sjtable trlabel">King's<br />Rest<br /></td>
      <td class="sjtable sjitem"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="sjtable">
      <td class="sjtable trlabel">Siege of<br />Boralus<br /></td>
      <td class="sjtable sjitem"></td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: There are plenty of ways to store data across sessions - with cookies, cache, using a local/online database and sending a GET request to fetch your data...

Comment: You can save the data with stringified data. Perhaps I guess that you have a bunch of dungeons with name and status (done or not). So you can save your current status with json like `states = {'name1': true, 'name2': false}`. And then you can save the state like `localStorage.setItem('dungeons', JSON.stringify(states))`. And you will need to pull the saved data back. 
`let states = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('dungeons'))`.
I hope it would help you a bit.

Comment: @AlexisRichard definitely something I can work with. thank you. ill give it a try and get back 2 you.

Comment: Sounds cool. There is something you have to know. Browsers don't give you sufficient space for the localStorage - basically 5MB. So I recommend you to save dungeons you have done by using array rather than json object.
So you can have your dungeons list like `dungeons = ['name1', 'name2', ... 'name100']` and store them in local storage with `localStorage.setItem('dungeons', JSON.stringify(dungeons))`

Comment: @AlexisRichard nice tip although I'm not planning to have this on the web, it's solely for my own use on my machine. will that be an issue?

Comment: Yeah, so you have a html file in your disk and just open it to mark your dungeons as complete. Then the localStorage might be messed down. If you want to have a clean localStorage space, you can create a simple chrome extension to manage your dungeons. Then you will have an independent localStorage space for that.

Comment: @AlexisRichard i see. i will look into that aswell. thank you very much.